# 17th Century term for Mother

Tags: writing, archaicisms

I'm writing a story where my main character calls out for her mother, and I'm having trouble with what word I should be using. 
The story is set around the 1660s London, my main character is of low class, and she's 17 years old.

Comment: @user067531 All i get from it is "mama" which was dated back in 1705 which is relatively close to what im looking for, but not exactly. The original poster in the link was also dealing with a child while my character is older. Of course i don't know if all of that makes a difference, but I want to be sure.